# How to apply no fill to textbox in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I've added TextBox so I can move it to desired location.  But when I try to remove it's background (In MS Word, it's equivalent to Format->Shape Fill->No Fill), it's not working.  How to make TextBox transparent?

Bellow is my code

```
$textBoxStyle = [
    'marginLeft' => Converter::cmToPixel(5.5),
    'positioning' => 'relative',
    'marginTop' => round(Converter::cmToPixel(14.55)),
    'width' => Converter::cmToPixel(6),
    'height' => Converter::cmToPixel(1),
    'borderColor' => '#fff',
    'borderSize' => 0,
    'posHorizontal' => 'absolute', 'posVertical' => 'absolute',
    'bgColor' => '#0000cccc',
    'fill' => ['color' => '#33CC99', 'bgColor' => '#33CC99'],
    'shading' => ['fill' => '#0000ffff'],
    'bgColor' => ['fill' => '#0000ffff']
];

$textReport = $section->addTextBox($textBoxStyle);

$textReport->addText("Report", [
    'name' => 'Arial', 
    'size' => 15, 
    'color' => '#ccc', 
    'bold' => true, 
    'italic' => true
]);
```

`bgColor,shading & fill` in styles are for testing.  It's not working.

Comment: did you try background-color ??

Answer (score 0):

Class for Textbox is initiated with style parameters like below. Taken from [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Element/TextBox.php).

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\TextBox as TextBoxStyle;

class TextBox extends AbstractContainer
{
    public function __construct($style = null)
    {
        $this->style = $this->setNewStyle(new TextBoxStyle(), $style);
    }
}
```

TextBoxStyle is extending from Image class([link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Style/TextBox.php#L25)). Image class is extending from Frame([link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Style/Image.php#L23)). Fill options in PHPWord are implemented in Fill class([link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Style/Fill.php#L28)). Since Textbox style is handled as Image, I guess, it is not possible for you to set its fill value.